# AngularJS Watch template for class

Tags: jquery, dom, angularjs

I have an angular app that at a certain point injects a class via jquery into the DOM.  I'm trying to build a directive that is restricted to that class and can act at the point that this class exists.  I have used the $watch directive before, but not in a situation like this.  The problem I have is that I want to restrict the directive to the dynamic class and add a link function to do stuff, and this class may exist on several elements at any given time.  I'm not sure how to facilitate this.

Here's a Plunk of what I mean

http://plnkr.co/edit/1cyEZt8SgohnWLkpLnbL?p=preview

Comment: Why not inject the class inside the directive instead of via jquery?

Comment: that would certainly work, the problem I'm faced with is I'm trying to do this currently with a lightbox plugin from jquery.  I've looked for a way to have a lightbox effect in straight angular but haven't found a great solution.  Basically I have a directive that calls the plugin to create the lightbox, once the lightbox is in view I want to add my dynamic content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `$compile` the element after you've modified it.

```
$("#DynamicDiv").addClass("dynamic");
$compile($("#DynamicDiv"))($scope);
```

In [this fork of your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Epw8lMBAv6PbRl7iPE7y?p=preview), I moved those two lines to the controller to make it easier to get to the `$compile` service.